# How to sort / order the servers in Sublime SFTP?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I have around 30 servers which I connect to using Sublime SFTP in Linux.  They appear to be randomly ordered in the File->SFTP->Browser Server menu.  (I just added a new one, and it was placed in the lower third of the listings.)  I have written to the developers a few times without reply.

Can someone say how the ordering works and if there is a way to change it?

For the record, I have searched the contents of all related files I could find and find no mention of any of my servers which could indicate their defined order.

The .json format of a server config file is as follows:

```
{
//  The tab key will cycle through the settings when first created
//  Visit http:wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/settings for help
//  sftp, ftp or ftps

   "type": "sftp",

   "sync_down_on_open": true,
   "sync_same_age": true,

   "host": "example.com",
   "user": "username",
   "password": "password",
   "port": "22",

   "remote_path": "/example/path/",
   "file_permissions": "664",
   "dir_permissions": "775",

   "extra_list_connections": 0,

   "connect_timeout": 30,
   "keepalive": 120,
   "ftp_passive_mode": true,
   "ftp_obey_passive_host": false,
   "ssh_key_file": "~/.ssh/id_rsa",
   "sftp_flags": ["-F", "/path/to/ssh_config"],

   "preserve_modification_times": false,
   "remote_time_offset_in_hours": 0,
   "remote_encoding": "utf-8",
   "remote_locale": "C",
   "allow_config_upload": false,
}
```

Comment: Could you post an example of the json structure?

Comment: Structure added. Sorry for the delay.